# On Angular, is binding to FormGroup (instead to a 'real model') a bad practice?

Tags: angular, architecture, angular-reactive-forms

I have a sample reactive form with the following structure:

```
- id
- firstName
- lastName
- siblings
  - id
  - firstName
  - lastName
```

Siblings is an array rendered by children components. I tested two methods of binding parent/children:

1) Using the FormGroup

`<app-child *ngFor="let sibling of form.get('siblings').controls" [formGroup]="sibling"></app-child>`

2) Using the 'real model'

`<app-child *ngFor="let sibling of model.siblings; let i = index;" [model]="sibling" (changed)=updateSiblingModel($event,i)>`

Both worked fine. My question is: **is one approach considered superior to the other?**

Reactive forms have an almost 1:1 relationship to a real model (obtained by `this.form.value`) plus some interesting perks such as cascading validators and events. It works really well but I feel that I'm extracting out 'too much logic/structure' from the child-component to the outer component.

Binding to the model also works fine, but I have more wiring to do (such as `(changed)=updateSiblingModel($event,i)`, but I feel it's a bit more cohesive.

Here's the complete example comparing the 2 strategies:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-binding

I don't have a lot of experience with larger Angular projects, so I'm also wondering if any approach scales better than the other.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

One key difference I see between the "form model" and the "data model" is that the "form model" only contains the data actually on the form.

If your data model has an id property, the id most likely does not appear in your form, so it won't be a part of your "form model". Same for potentially other fields like "last update date" or timestamps.

Plus if someone later decides to group some of your form fields for additional validation, it could break your expected "form model".

Personally, I would always use the data model as you have more control over it. You can perform operations on it more readily such as sorting or filtering. You can more easily store it in local storage for offline operation.

Plus, if the application gets larger over time you can move to a more formal state management library, such as NgRx which will work with your "data model".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about the binding difference between [Ng Model](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) and [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

`ng-model` is better for dealing with simple binding while `reactive form` provides much powerful support for `Form` manipulation such as `type` (like boolean, string, array etc), `structure` (reuse the structure/ form group like add other people with first and last name), `validation` (auto valid the input and form), `default value` (value changes depend on other field), `disable` etc.

In short, `reactive form` is good for complicated form, dynamic form (like field value or validation changes depends on other field) and code maintenance.

Comment: I'm actually asking about 2 different strategies within reactive forms.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use FormGroup bindings but keep the logic/structure inside each child. I found this solution to give me the best balance for the objectives I was looking for.

*Disclaimer: I'm not claiming the originality of this solution, it's the result from days of researching and testing many solutions on the internet.*

So the parent component binds to the child using a FormGroup:

```
<div class="sibling" *ngFor="let sibling of getSiblings(); let i = index;">
    <app-child [form]="sibling" (deleted)="deleteSibling(i)"></app-child>
</div>
```

The getSiblings() method in the parent is just a simple helper:

```
getSiblings(): AbstractControl[] {
  return (<FormArray>this.form.get('siblings')).controls;
}
```

The key difference is how the siblings FormGroups are created on the parent:

```
addSibling() {
  (<FormArray>this.form.controls.siblings).push(ChildComponent.toFormGroup());
}
```

addSibling() above uses a static method from the child component to create the blank FormGroup:

```
static toFormGroup(model: any = {}) {
  return new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(model.id, Validators.required),
    firstName: new FormControl(model.firstName, Validators.required),
    lastName: new FormControl(model.lastName, Validators.required),
  });
}
```

As seen above, not only blank FormGroups can be created. The loadModel method on the parent can take advantage of each child logic to create filed FormGroups too. Here we have only one child type but we could have many:

```
loadModel(model: any) {
  this.form.patchValue(model);

  const formArray = this.form.get('siblings') as FormArray;
  while (formArray.length) {
    formArray.removeAt(0);
  }
  model.siblings.forEach(s => formArray.push(ChildComponent.toFormGroup(s)));
}
```

Sorting and filter are not complicated either. There are multiple strategies here but as a simple test case:

```
orderChildren() {
  this.currentModel.siblings = this.currentModel.siblings.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  this.loadModel(this.currentModel);
}
```

With this approach I can use Reactive Forms cascading features like valid status, pristine/dirty flags, change events, etc, while keeping the logic/structure of each children inside it's component class. Just as an example the cascading validity can be seen in action (red borders) on the final solution.

As the main concern of binding to FormGroup was that logic/structure of the children had to be moved to the parent, with this approach this is avoided and hence I'm more willing to accept that this cannot be considered a bad practice.

The complete example can be seen on the StackBlitz:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-binding